# How TRC-20 Contract Interaction via HTTP?

Tags: php, api, post, blockchain, tron

[trc20-contract-interaction](https://developers.tron.network/docs/trc20-contract-interaction#transfer)

```
wallet/triggersmartcontract
Description: Trigger smart contract
demo: curl -X POST https://127.0.0.1:8090/wallet/triggersmartcontract -d '{
"contract_address":"419E62BE7F4F103C36507CB2A753418791B1CDC182",
"function_selector":"transfer(address,uint256)",
"parameter":"00000000000000000000004115208EF33A926919ED270E2FA61367B2DA3753DA0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032",
"fee_limit":100000000,
"call_value":0,
"owner_address":"41977C20977F412C2A1AA4EF3D49FEE5EC4C31CDFB"
}'
```

1. Where put a privateKey?
2. How generate `parameter` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the flow is like this

1. wallet/triggersmartcontract
2. sign
3. broadcast

Back to your question:

1. How to generate the `parameter` field?

The parameter field can be generated from [Parameter and return value encoding and decoding](https://developers.tron.network/docs/parameter-and-return-value-encoding-and-decoding) documentation.

An example: the function

`transfer (412ed5dd8a98aea00ae32517742ea5289761b2710e, 50000)` is then encoded with an output
`0000000000000000000000002ed5dd8a98aea00ae32517742ea5289761b2710e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ba43b7400`

2. Where put a privateKey?

The privateKey is inserted during the sign transaction. The first wallet/triggersmartcontract then sign using the `/wallet/gettransactionsign` call. Then the signed transaction is used to broadcast `/wallet/broadcasttransaction`.

So instead of making a transaction in this [API Signature and Broadcast Flow](https://developers.tron.network/docs/api-signature-and-broadcast-flow) documentation. Your transaction is actually a triggersmartcontract transaction, the sign and broadcast flow remains.